# Not receiving.csv file as data in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

I am trying to download `.csv` using `Ajax call`.

Button to call `Ajax` call

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default blue-btn" onclick="downloadCsv()">Ajax call Export</button>
```

**downloadCsv() javascript function**

```js
     function downloadCsv()
     {
      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : 'url'
       dataType : "text/csv",
       scriptCharset: "UTF-8",
          success : function(data) {
        alert("about to download .csv file "+data);
        console.log(data);
       },
       error : function(data) {
        alert("Failed to get the data");
        alert(data); 
       }
       });
      
     }
```

The above function sends the ajax request to controller and pull the data from database. and my `controller` is able generate .csv file.

But the data is not coming to **success** . Every time I get alert from 
error that, `Failed to get the data`.

The interesting thing is to note that, `console.log(data);` in success is showing the correct response in console.

When I tested using link

```
<a href="myurl">Download csv</a>
```

this is working perfect and I am able to download the `.csv` file.

1. How do I short out this problem
2. How can I download `.csv` using Ajax call file as I am able to download using above shown link.
3. Do I have to write some more code or as soon downloadCsv() function
   get called I'll get the download option.

Comment: Is your controller being hit by Ajax?

Comment: Yes my controller is hit by Ajax.

Comment: Why are you using ajax here?? Why don't you use anchor to refer your controller/action directly.

Comment: That is working I have mention in the question.. by every Time I need to pass a id on based on that my controller will decide what to generate.

Comment: but you can pass your id directly in your url.